# Disable not selected options when a user selects more than 'x' options

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

In a option list I would like the user to be able to select a maximum of 3 options.

On a form of four options, when the user has selected three options, it should disable the fourth non-selected option.

I have the following setup:

```
import {
  Component,
  Input,
  ViewChild,
  OnInit,
  AfterViewInit
} from "@angular/core";
import { MatSelectionList } from "@angular/material/list";

type Option = {
  key: string;
  enabled: boolean;
};

@Component({
  selector: "app-list-component",
  template: `
    <mat-selection-list>
      <mat-list-option
        *ngFor="let option of options"
        checkboxPosition="before"
        [selected]="option.enabled == true"
        [disabled]="
          selectedOptionsCount >= maxSelectedFilters && !option.enabled
        "
      >
        {{ option.key }}
      </mat-list-option>
    </mat-selection-list>
  `,
  styleUrls: ["./list.component.css"]
})
export class ListComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  options: Option[];
  selectedOptionsCount: number;

  @Input() filters: string[];
  @Input() selectedFilters: string[];
  @Input() maxSelectedFilters: number;

  @ViewChild(MatSelectionList) selectionList: MatSelectionList;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.options = this.filters.map((key) => ({
      key,
      enabled: this.selectedFilters.includes(key)
    }));
    // initially set the count
    this.selectedOptionsCount = this.selectedFilters.length;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.selectionList.selectionChange.subscribe(() => {
      // update the count based on the selection change
      this.selectedOptionsCount = this.selectionList.selectedOptions.selected.length;
    });
  }
}
```

With this setup when you select an option and then de-select that same option, only then you see the non-selected items being disabled.

How should you pick up those changes?

---

## Edit:

The following seems to do the trick. On the `mat-list-option` add a template variable using a '#', and use that to get the 'selected' property:

```
// 
// ...
     <mat-list-option
        #foo
        *ngFor="let option of options"
        checkboxPosition="before"
        [selected]="option.enabled == true"
        [disabled]="selectedOptionsCount >= maxSelectedFilters && !foo.selected"
      >
// ...
```

Source: https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-kare-wc26k?file=/src/components/list.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

**.html**

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Toppings</mat-label>
    <mat-select [formControl]="toppings" multiple (selectionChange)="changed()">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping"
            [disabled]="toppings.value?.length > '2' && check(topping)">{{topping}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

**.ts**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { FormControl } from "@angular/forms";

/** @title Select with multiple selection */
@Component({
  selector: "select-multiple-example",
  templateUrl: "select-multiple-example.html"
})
export class SelectMultipleExample {
  toppings = new FormControl();
  toppingList: string[] = [
    "Extra cheese",
    "Mushroom",
    "Onion",
    "Pepperoni",
    "Sausage",
    "Tomato"
  ];
  mySelections: any;

  changed() {
    this.mySelections = this.toppings.value;
    this.toppings.setValue(this.mySelections);
    console.log(this.toppings);
  }
  check(value: any) {
    if (this.mySelections.includes(value)) {
      return false;
    }
    else {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Demo:https://stackblitz.com/edit/mur-mat-select-checkbox-disable-unselect-value?file=src/app/select-multiple-example.ts